# Color for "Edit"

Tags: website-design, buttons, color

In the Bootstrap color scheme, the Danger button is red, OK/Confirm/Success buttons are green, secondary is gray (for Cancel and such), etc.

I want to have an Edit button to go along with my "Delete" button which is the same shade of red Bootstrap uses. Their "Info" button and "Warning" button doesn't seem like the correct colors to use for an edit  button. The secondary/default button seems like it's less important or a backup kind of button (like Cancel), and the primary seems too important, like it's the main action. What color should an Edit button be then?

[image]

Comment: You didn't mention the link. Is that not an option for you?

Comment: @RogerAttrill The link is the same color as the Primary button, so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap colour scheme is really just a starting point if you don't already have a branding or style guide in place for your organisation or project, so I certainly would only take what is appropriate for you rather than just applying everything that is there.

If you really want to apply the bootstrap theme, then the default button style is what you should go with, and then depending on the amount of emphasis required you can look at either using the Primary action colour scheme or define a secondary action colour if it is not as important.

Answer (score 1):

My manager once told me, **"Don't take my word as gospel. I am just bouncing ideas off of you"**

Bootstrap's guide for button colors is good for reference but then there are way more types of buttons like Terminal Action, Step Action, etc.

**Edit** in itself feels like a *default* button but that can change depending on the context.

If **Edit** is the primary action on a page (like on the Profile page) then you have to use it as *Primary*

*PS : If you're unsure, go with Default. Can't go wrong with that.*

Answer (score 0):

You already correctly stated the common interpretation of each default color in Bootstrap buttons options.

It's commonly accepted that a red color is a negative/dangerous action. An orange one is an alert action, while a green color is normally associated to a positive/safe action.

All other colors are just specific to Bootstrap theme styles, like the blue as a primary button, which on a default white BG gets more contrast than the default white button.

So, unless you won't make it a primary action in your design/page, you should probably use a neutral button like the default button.

That said, it depends on your design, of course. E.G. if you have a dark background, probably a lighter button becomes your primary button while a dark button becomes your default button.